# placing image based on screen coordinates in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, orthographic

I'v been looking into how to place images in OpenGL based on screen coordinates rather than OpenGL's Carthesian-based coordinates (orthographic). I've managed to partially solve my problem, but somewhere the calculations is off. The top image is based on OpenGL placing the image at 0,0. The bottom is my recalculation, but instead of being in the top-left corner, part of the image is offscreen and there is a gap to the left.

orthographic projection:

```
glm::ortho(-((float)WIDTH / (float)HEIGHT), (float)WIDTH / (float)HEIGHT, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)
```

Conversion:

```
    // Convert OpenGL coords to screen coords
    position.x = glLeft + (2.0f / (float)WIDTH * position.x);
    position.y = glTop + (-2.0f / (float)HEIGHT * position.y);
```

[image]

Comment: Which functionality of OpenGL do you use to *place* an image on screen?

Comment: @stgatilov I'm using shaders

Comment: The easiest way to get correct position transformation in vertex shader is to multiply it by *gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix* matrix. In fact you are now trying to calculate projection matrix yourself instead of using the builtin matrix.
Also, it seems that both input and output coordinates are for the CENTER of the image. Without knowing the size of the image you won't be able to place its corner into the top-left corner.

Comment: @stgatilov gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix is deprecated and you might want to look at the difference between perspective and orthographic.

Comment: The projection matrix is deprecated, which only means that you manage it yourself. It seems that glm::ortho returns the projection matrix. Pass it to your shader as uniform and multiply by it.

Comment: @stgatilov Ok, your comments shows that you don't know the bare basics of using GLSL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83657/discussion-between-spicyweenie-and-stgatilov).

Comment: I really wonder what you are trying to achieve with your projection matrix. Usually, one incorporates the aspect ratio to exactly correct for it, so that squares in eye space are preserved as squares in window space. However, your matrix just  derives a scale factor from the aspect ratio, but does in no way correct for it.